# Getting the "ImportError: No module named selenium" even though Selenium is installed

Tags: python, selenium

I installed selenium with `pip3 install selenium`, but still getting an ImportError.

I even tried reinstalling again just to make sure, but it says

```
requirement already satisfied:
urllib3 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from selenium) (1.25.9)
```

Do I need to point Python somewhere for it to see it or something?

Comment: What version of python are you using?  How do you run python -- from the command line, or do you use an IDE?

Comment: Python 3.8.3, running from VS Code on macOS Catalina

Comment: What does this show when you run it inside VS Code: `import sys; print(sys.path)`

Comment: ['', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python38.zip', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload', '/Users/ZEMEL/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages']

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try running your script using `python3` instead of just `python`:

`python3 script.py`

You can reinstall or upgrade `selenium` using `sudo`:

`pip3 install -U selenium`

Comment: You can python virtual environment which will help you to manage libraries more easily.            
https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html